# How to add up multiple values per row in Numbers using SUMIF?

Tags: numbers

[image: example table]

I would like to use a formula to add the values from columns B,C and D for all rows where checkbox A is set.

In this example, this would be 1+5+9+3+7+11 = 36.

Unfortunately, my attempts like

```
SUMIF(A;TRUE();SUM(Value 1;Value 2;Value 3))
```

have failed. What would the formula have to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it also has an extra closing parenthesis at the end, your formula fails because [SUMIF()](https://support.apple.com/guide/functions/sumif-ffa58cd24e/12.2/web/1.0) requires its test values to have the same number of sequential cells with the values to be summed.

I can think of more than one way of implementing what you are trying to accomplish with one being the addition of a column calculating the subtotal of a row  when the checkbox for that row is TRUE. Below is the screenshot of an example with this solution.

[image]

The other could be to add a column again but for the unconditional subtotal of each row and then sum those subtotals using a SUMIF() whose test values would be coming from the column with the checkboxes.

---

**UPDATE**

As the poster suggested in a comment to this answer and assuming there are not too many columns in the actual spreadsheet to utilize it, another solution would involve the following formula:

```
SUM(SUMIF(A;TRUE();Value 1);SUMIF(A;TRUE();Value 2);SUMIF(A;TRUE();Value 3))
```

This formula would find the sum of the cells per column with TRUE in the checkbox cells in the same rows with them and then take the sum of all the column-based sums.

Comment: The above table is only a very simplified example. An additional column would work technically, but unfortunately not so well in terms of content, which is why I am looking for a way to calculate the result directly with a formula. Nevertheless a very good suggestion - thanks for that. Thanks also for pointing out the missing parenthesis. I have just added it above.

Comment: Your suggestion led me to the solution: I can simply add three SUMIF. Would you like to add this to your answer? Then we can close yours as "accepted" answer: `SUM(SUMIF(A;TRUE();B);SUMIF(A;TRUE();C);SUMIF(A;TRUE();D))`

Comment: @Ben Thx for letting me know. Pls see my updated answer.